# how to estimate the distance between 2 point clouds on pcl

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

How can i get the distance between 2 point clouds in pcl? I want to find the distance between two parallel and irregulary surfaces. But using the nearest neighbor method do not get the distance in the normal direction. How can i do it?

Comment: Does it have to be fast? :D

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
float pcl::geometry::squaredDistance  ( const PointT &  p1,  
  const PointT &  p2 )    [inline]
```

The function will returns: the squared Euclidean distance between 2 points.

The procedure could be

1. Select one arbitrary point on plane 1
2. Calculate average distance
   between the arbitrary point to all points on plane 2

The plane 1 and 2 are parallel, so the output shouldn't be the same regardless the point location on the plane 1?